# PHP Store variable without echoing?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a switch to change the text/image depending on the date, however, for some reason I have to actually `echo $current_date;` otherwise my switch doesn't seem to pick up the value?

```
$start_date = '2018-10-15';
$end_date = '2018-10-27';
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');

echo $current_date;
    while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    switch($current_date) {
        case "2018-10-15":
            $text = 'todays text';
            $image = 'https://www.image.com';
            break;
        case "2018-10-16":
            $text = 'todays text2';
            $image = 'https://www.image.com2';
            break;
    }
}

echo $text;
```

https://repl.it/repls/EthicalJuicyLocks

As you can see from the REPL above. Is there any way that I can pass the value of `$current_date` into the switch without the need to call it?

Comment: I can't see any code.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Hm, looks ok without `echo` in https://3v4l.org/7Rbtv

Comment: your repl works fine for me, if i comment out the `echo $current_date` it still echos `'todays text'`

Comment: Also you can write `echo $current_date, "\n";` for new line. Because everithing else works good for me

Comment: Using `echo` doesn't change the state of your variable at all. Your code works fine without it.

You're making a correlation that doesn't exist. I suggest further testing.

Comment: your repl work fine for me. without using 'echo'

Comment: What is the exact output you're expecting? The code works correctly and switches correctly when removing the echo

Comment: really? for me it just has no output at all after removing the echo.

Oh, actually -- it's whilst it's within a while loop but I had taken it out (see updated link) https://repl.it/repls/EthicalJuicyLocks

Comment: That while loop from your latest repl makes rather little sense. For one thing, it never terminates, because the values you are checking for inside the loop condition don’t get modified inside the loop body at all … So yes, in that case it makes a difference if you output something before the never-ending while loop, or not … in the first case you at least get to see _something_ whereas in the latter, not. The overall code however still makes little sense.

Comment: @misorude but won't the current_day value be different each day? I just want to change the text within those several days so my thinking was, get the start / end date, use switch between the start/end dates and then have a default as the final case which is just the standard text. I guess it doesn't really need the while loop/start/end dates does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not echoing the date, as it has absolutely no impact in the switching.
The problem is your while loop never ends (`$start_date` and `$end_date` are static, so `start_date` is always less than or equal to `$end_date`)

As such, your never ending while loop prevents any output being sent to stdout. Echoing the date beforehand only gives you the illusion of something working or not working, but it's only the illusion.

Preventing infinite loops is important. You should always put some controls to prevent loops running away. It could be a counter and stop after a given number of iterations, a stop placed after the next iteration produces a variation in the result smaller than a given threshold, etc.

If what you want is just entering some part of your code if the current date is between start and end dates you can use a two-clause if

```
if ($current_date >= $start_date && $current_date <= $end_date)
{
  // Do whatever you need when you are between the boundary dates
}
```

Replace the while with this and let me know

Comment: Thank you, Javier for the detailed answer. I'm just a little bit confused how to tie start_date and end_date into the current_date, or with the switch only being on such select days, do I only need the current_date?

Comment: What is exactly what you want? Only do something if the current date is between start and end dates?

Comment: Yes that's correct--I only want to change the text/image if its within the start/end dates

Comment: I updated my answer, check the bottom part and let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks perfect, I had just tried the exact same with a while still... need to get my head around when to use if and when to use while... Thanks again!

Comment: Rule of thumb: everything inside an if gets executed once provided a condition is met, as `if` is non-looping control structure. On the other hand, `while` will evaluate the same condition and loop itself as many times as needed (probably many times per second) as long as that condition keeps being satisfied

Comment: Thank you very much, I hear you loud and clear, that makes  a lot of sense!!

Comment: Glad you got this figured out!

Answer (score 0):

```
while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date))
```

this is a infinite loop. 
start_date and end_date no changed in while loop

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense-however, won't the current_date be updating and so it should only enter the while loop if the current_date is within the start/end dates?

Comment: you have to  consider current_date in while condition for  ending while loop